# If $f(x)=ax^{2p}+bx^p+c\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, prove that $f'(x)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $R$ is denoted by $R[x]$.

$\mathbb{I}_p[m]$ is the integers mod $m$.

When $p$ is a prime, we will usually denote the field $\mathbb{I}_p[x]$ by $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $f(x)=\sum^n_{i=0}a_ix^i\in R[x]$ has degree $n\geq1$, define its derivative $f'(x)\in R[x]$ by
\begin{equation*}
f'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+...+na_nx^{n-1};
\end{equation*}
if $f(x)$ is a constant polynomial, define its derivative to be the zero polynomial.

My efforts:

$x^p=x,x^{2p}=x^2,f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

On one hand, $f'(x)=2pax^{2p-1}+pbx^{p-1}$.

On the other hand, $f'(x)=2ax+b$.

Since both are correct, $px^{2p-1}=x$ and $px^{p-1}=1$. So $px^{p-1}x=x$, $px^p=x$, $px=x$, $p=1$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: $x$ is a variable, not an element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ (otherwise, we would write $\mathbb{F}_p[x] = \mathbb{F}_{p}$). So you can't say that $x^{p} = x$, and you should apply differentiation directly to the $f$ (for example, $(x^{p})' = px^{p-1}$ which IS zero since characteristic is $p$.